# Fastest way to load data into Sql CE database on windows mobile 5

Tags: c#, sql, windows-mobile, sql-server-ce

I am developing an application on Windows Mobile 5, in which part of the application loads a load of data (2000+) in from an IEnumerable.

At the moment I am doing a check to see if the Id exists in the database, and depending on the result I am performing an Insert or an Update statement  (using the ExecuteNonQuery method of a SqlCeCommand).

So far it's performing just fine, but I'm wondering if there was a quicker/better way to do it, which might boost performance.

I've looked at some sort of Bulk Insert, but from what I understand this will only work for inserts.  There is a good chance that some items in my IEnumerable<> will already exist in the database, and if so will need updating. So Bulk Copy/Insert wont do - is that right?

Any answers appreciated.

Many thanks,

ETFairfax.

**EDIT:** This is the code I've ended up with.  The performance increase is amazing.  I've gone from it taking 30 second to save 1000 records, to it being a blink of an eye.  Feel free to suggest further improvements....

```
public void MergeData(IEnumerable<T> entities)
    {   
        using (var cmd = GlobalConnection.Instance.Connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
            cmd.IndexName = "PK_" + this.TableName;
            cmd.CommandText = this.TableName;

            using (SqlCeResultSet sqlCeResultSet = cmd.ExecuteResultSet(ResultSetOptions.Updatable))
            {
                foreach (var entityToSave in entities)
                {
                    bool recordAlreadyExists = sqlCeResultSet.Seek(DbSeekOptions.FirstEqual, entityToSave.Id);

                    if (recordAlreadyExists)
                    {
                        //Do an Update
                        sqlCeResultSet.Read();

                        PopulateForUpdate(sqlCeResultSet, entityToSave);

                        sqlCeResultSet.Update();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Do an Insert
                        SqlCeUpdatableRecord insertRecord = sqlCeResultSet.CreateRecord();

                        PopulateForInsert(insertRecord, entityToSave);

                        sqlCeResultSet.Insert(insertRecord);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TableDirect instead of the query processor will probably get you a 10x improvement in performance if you're hitting just a single table. Just Seek on the ID index, if the row exists, Update, otherwise Insert.  Use a SqlCeResultSet for traversing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Can you clarify something for me please?  For what part of the process should I be using TableDirect?  I assume you mean I should be using TableDirect/Seek to help determine if the ID already exists, and I should still use a SqlCeCommand to perform the actual Insert/Update. Is that right?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476929/how-to-improve-this-code post helped me find the answer to my question above.

Comment: Yes, the answer that uses TableDirect is applicable.